# How to maintain a connection to a 3rd party API throughout my Web Application

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm writing a Java Web Application with Jersey running on Tomcat with a MySQL database.  Nothing fancy so far, just a few Webpages that contain ajax calls to the backend REST web service (Jersey) which queries the database and returns the dataset to be rendered on the web page.  So far so good.

One of my REST methods needs to connect to another Application Server via a 3rd party API.

The connection setup looks like this:

```
ServerObject svr = new ServerObject();
svr.setHostname("192.168.1.1");
svr.setPort(21);
svr.setUsername("user");
svr.setPassword("password");

try{
svr.connect()
}catch(Exception e){
e.printstacktrace();
}
```

The connect() method is very time consuming so it is not practical to establish new connections every single request.  What is the best way to maintain a connection to this server via this API call?

In prior applications I've built, I used the Servlet's init() method to setup these connections.
I'm using Jersey this time so I don't know if I can or even should do the same thing?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a class that handles your connection(s) to this 3rd party api with keep the connection open and add all methods that you need (init connection, get connection, perform request, etc).

After that, you can just call init of this class on InitialContext on your web application.

Remenber also to define a reconnection stategy.

I think it's on way to handle it.